# Running an ant task only when a file has changed

Tags: ant

In Ant, I am trying to achieve a simple task: If couple of files are modified a compiler should run. I have seen many solutions using OutOfDate, UpToDate and Modified. I dont want to use OutOfDate and UpToDate because I wont be able to use the task if the files have been modified on the same day. I can use modified but there is no way to call another task - my compiler task, from the modifier task. Is there any other solution apart from these?

Comment: OutOfDate isn't limited to files modified before today. It will detect whether target files are seconds, days, or years out of date.

Comment: @ChadNouis I was not aware of it, but if am not wrong the OutOfDate is from ant-contrib, I dont want to use ant-contrib. Thanks, can you think of any other solution?

Answer (score 8):

Using `<uptodate>` with a following `<antcall>` to a conditional `<target>` will give you what you're looking for:

```
<project name="ant-uptodate" default="run-tests">
    <tstamp>
        <format property="ten.seconds.ago" offset="-10" unit="second" 
            pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa"/>
    </tstamp>

    <target name="uptodate-test">
        <uptodate property="build.notRequired" targetfile="target-file.txt">
            <srcfiles dir= "." includes="source-file.txt"/>
        </uptodate>

        <antcall target="do-compiler-conditionally"/>
    </target>

    <target name="do-compiler-conditionally" unless="build.notRequired">
        <echo>Call compiler here.</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="source-older-than-target-test">
        <touch file="source-file.txt" datetime="${ten.seconds.ago}"/>
        <touch file="target-file.txt" datetime="now"/>
        <antcall target="uptodate-test"/>
    </target>

    <target name="source-newer-than-target-test">
        <touch file="target-file.txt" datetime="${ten.seconds.ago}"/>
        <touch file="source-file.txt" datetime="now"/>
        <antcall target="uptodate-test"/>
    </target>

    <target name="run-tests" 
        depends="source-older-than-target-test,source-newer-than-target-test"/>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply but I guess I have confused you and hence this is not what I was looking for. Is there any way to get the time the file was last modified in ant?